# Parsing XML tags with small difference in names

Tags: xpath

I have an XML file to parse in which the element tags are of the form:

```
<mensa-1>
..
</mensa-1>

<mensa-2>
..
</mensa-2>
```

Is it possible to parse such elements via Xpath when the element names differ via a number at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following XPath expression returns all the elements whose names start with "mensa-":

```
//*[starts-with(name(),'mensa-')]
```